# How show hierarchy tree collapsed on first time loaded

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to create a tree component. I'm working with a mocked data and using react to create this component.

I would like when is loaded by first time, show collapse all children of their first parents. To show collapse or not I add a class called collapsed that have `display: none` like this:

```
<div className={`hierarchy ${level} ${isCollapsed() ? "collapsed" : ""}`}>
```

And function is this:

```
const isCollapsed = () => {
    const index: number = hiddenBranchs.findIndex( (hiddenId: string) => hiddenId === branch.value);
    return (index >=0) ? true : false;
};
```

When load first time call this function:

```
export const showCollapsed = (branch: IHierarchyBranch) => {
    // Get parent Ids
    const parentIds: Array<string> = getFirstChildrenIds(branch);
    // Get all ids
    const ids: Array<string> = getIdOfChildrens(branch);
    // remove parent ids from all ids to load first branch with their first children
    const idsWithoutParents: Array<string> = removeAllIdsContainedInOtherArray(
        ids,
        parentIds
    );
    return idsWithoutParents;
};
```

My problem is that I dont know how show collapsed and behaviour that show on picture. ( I hope, that with picture undertand me better I'm what I would like to do). I store ids on redux when I call this function:

```
    const onUpdatedHiddenBranchs = (ids: Array<string>, show: boolean) => {
        let items: Array<string> = [];
        if (!show) {
            items = [...hiddenBranchs, ...ids];
        } else {
            const copyItems: Array<string> = [...hiddenBranchs];
            const duplicatedItems: Array<string> = findDuplicatedItems(
                copyItems
            );
            items = copyItems.filter((item: string) => {
                return !ids.includes(item);
            });
            items = [...items, ...duplicatedItems];
        }
        onUpdateHiddenBranchs(items);
    };
```

Here is the data with I'm working:

```
export const smallData: any = {
    value: "22-hierarchy",
    label: "HIERARCHY",
    type: "hierarchy",
    id: 22,
    children: [
        {
            label: "EXAMPLE LIST",
            value: "4720-dma",
            icon: "dma",
            favourite: false,
            sensorizable: true,
            id: 4720,
            parentId: null,
            tag: null,
            alarms: {
                dmaId: 4720,
                numAlarms: 0,
                numSectorsWithAlarms: 2,
                codeAlarmList: null,
                nameAlarmList: null,
                showAlarm: false,
            },
            children: [
                {
                    label: "Enric1",
                    value: "4838-dma",
                    icon: "dma",
                    favourite: false,
                    sensorizable: true,
                    id: 4838,
                    parentId: 4720,
                    tag: null,
                    alarms: {
                        dmaId: 4838,
                        numAlarms: 0,
                        numSectorsWithAlarms: 0,
                        codeAlarmList: null,
                        nameAlarmList: null,
                        showAlarm: null,
                    },
                    children: [
                        {
                            label: "Gran Abonado",
                            value: "12-tag",
                            icon: "tag",
                            favourite: false,
                            sensorizable: false,
                            id: 1,
                            parentId: 4838,
                            tag: null,
                            alarms: null,
                            children: [
                                {
                                    label: "TAG_ING",
                                    value: "4845-dma",
                                    icon: "sensor",
                                    favourite: false,
                                    sensorizable: false,
                                    id: 4845,
                                    parentId: 4838,
                                    tag: {
                                        id: 1,
                                        name: "Gran Abonado",
                                        autogenerated: null,
                                    },
                                    alarms: {
                                        dmaId: 4845,
                                        numAlarms: 0,
                                        numSectorsWithAlarms: 0,
                                        codeAlarmList: null,
                                        nameAlarmList: null,
                                        showAlarm: null,
                                    },
                                    children: [],
                                },
                            ],
                        },
                    ],
                },
                {
                    label: "Enric2",
                    value: "4839-dma",
                    icon: "dma",
                    favourite: false,
                    sensorizable: true,
                    id: 4839,
                    parentId: 4720,
                    tag: null,
                    alarms: {
                        dmaId: 4839,
                        numAlarms: 0,
                        numSectorsWithAlarms: 0,
                        codeAlarmList: null,
                        nameAlarmList: null,
                        showAlarm: null,
                    },
                    children: [],
                },
                {
                    label: "Enric3",
                    value: "4840-dma",
                    icon: "dma",
                    favourite: false,
                    sensorizable: true,
                    id: 4840,
                    parentId: 4720,
                    tag: null,
                    alarms: {
                        dmaId: 4840,
                        numAlarms: 0,
                        numSectorsWithAlarms: 0,
                        codeAlarmList: null,
                        nameAlarmList: null,
                        showAlarm: null,
                    },
                    children: [],
                },
                {
                    label: "Enric4",
                    value: "4841-dma",
                    icon: "dma",
                    favourite: false,
                    sensorizable: true,
                    id: 4841,
                    parentId: 4720,
                    tag: null,
                    alarms: {
                        dmaId: 4841,
                        numAlarms: 0,
                        numSectorsWithAlarms: 0,
                        codeAlarmList: null,
                        nameAlarmList: null,
                        showAlarm: null,
                    },
                    children: [],
                },
                {
                    label: "N1",
                    value: "4825-dma",
                    icon: "dma",
                    favourite: false,
                    sensorizable: true,
                    id: 4825,
                    parentId: 4720,
                    tag: null,
                    alarms: {
                        dmaId: 4825,
                        numAlarms: 0,
                        numSectorsWithAlarms: 0,
                        codeAlarmList: null,
                        nameAlarmList: null,
                        showAlarm: null,
                    },
                    children: [],
                },
                {
                    label: "N2",
                    value: "4826-dma",
                    icon: "dma",
                    favourite: false,
                    sensorizable: true,
                    id: 4826,
                    parentId: 4720,
                    tag: null,
                    alarms: {
                        dmaId: 4826,
                        numAlarms: 0,
                        numSectorsWithAlarms: 0,
                        codeAlarmList: null,
                        nameAlarmList: null,
                        showAlarm: null,
                    },
                    children: [
                        {
                            label: "HIJO-1",
                            value: "4827-dma",
                            icon: "dma",
                            favourite: false,
                            sensorizable: true,
                            id: 4827,
                            parentId: 4826,
                            tag: null,
                            alarms: {
                                dmaId: 4827,
                                numAlarms: 0,
                                numSectorsWithAlarms: 0,
                                codeAlarmList: null,
                                nameAlarmList: null,
                                showAlarm: null,
                            },
                            children: [
                                {
                                    label: "NUEVO-NIVEL",
                                    value: "4829-dma",
                                    icon: "dma",
                                    favourite: false,
                                    sensorizable: true,
                                    id: 4829,
                                    parentId: 4827,
                                    tag: null,
                                    alarms: {
                                        dmaId: 4829,
                                        numAlarms: 0,
                                        numSectorsWithAlarms: 0,
                                        codeAlarmList: null,
                                        nameAlarmList: null,
                                        showAlarm: null,
                                    },
                                    children: [
                                        {
                                            label: "Enric5",
                                            value: "4842-dma",
                                            icon: "dma",
                                            favourite: false,
                                            sensorizable: true,
                                            id: 4842,
                                            parentId: 4829,
                                            tag: null,
                                            alarms: {
                                                dmaId: 4842,
                                                numAlarms: 0,
                                                numSectorsWithAlarms: 0,
                                                codeAlarmList: null,
                                                nameAlarmList: null,
                                                showAlarm: null,
                                            },
                                            children: [
                                                {
                                                    label: "Otros",
                                                    value: "1-tag",
                                                    icon: "tag",
                                                    favourite: false,
                                                    sensorizable: false,
                                                    id: 5,
                                                    parentId: 4842,
                                                    tag: null,
                                                    alarms: null,
                                                    children: [
                                                        {
                                                            label: "TESTED",
                                                            value: "4843-dma",
                                                            icon: "dma",
                                                            favourite: false,
                                                            sensorizable: true,
                                                            id: 4843,
                                                            parentId: 4842,
                                                            tag: {
                                                                id: 5,
                                                                name: "Otros",
                                                                autogenerated: null,
                                                            },
                                                            alarms: {
                                                                dmaId: 4843,
                                                                numAlarms: 0,
                                                                numSectorsWithAlarms: 0,
                                                                codeAlarmList: null,
                                                                nameAlarmList: null,
                                                                showAlarm: null,
                                                            },
                                                            children: [],
                                                        },
                                                    ],
                                                },
                                            ],
                                        },
                                    ],
                                },
                            ],
                        },
                        {
                            label: "HIJO-2",
                            value: "4828-dma",
                            icon: "dma",
                            favourite: false,
                            sensorizable: true,
                            id: 4828,
                            parentId: 4826,
                            tag: null,
                            alarms: {
                                dmaId: 4828,
                                numAlarms: 0,
                                numSectorsWithAlarms: 0,
                                codeAlarmList: null,
                                nameAlarmList: null,
                                showAlarm: null,
                            },
                            children: [
                                {
                                    label: "NUEVO-NIVEL",
                                    value: "4830-dma",
                                    icon: "dma",
                                    favourite: false,
                                    sensorizable: true,
                                    id: 4830,
                                    parentId: 4828,
                                    tag: null,
                                    alarms: {
                                        dmaId: 4830,
                                        numAlarms: 0,
                                        numSectorsWithAlarms: 0,
                                        codeAlarmList: null,
                                        nameAlarmList: null,
                                        showAlarm: null,
                                    },
                                    children: [],
                                },
                            ],
                        },
                    ],
                },
            ],
        },
    ],
};
```

And here is my component:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

import { IHierarchyBranchProps, IHierarchyBranch } from "../main/interfaces";
import { getIdOfChildrens } from "../../utils/hierarhcy";

const HierarchyBranch = ({
    id,
    level,
    label,
    favourite,
    icon,
    children,
    branch,
    selectedId,
    hiddenBranchs,
    onUpdateSelectedBranch,
    onUpdatedHiddenBranchs,
    onUpdateFavourites,
    renderHierarchyBranch,
}: IHierarchyBranchProps): JSX.Element => {

    const [opened, setOpen] = useState<boolean>(true);

    const onSelectDma = () => {
        onUpdateSelectedBranch(id, branch);
    };

    const onOpenCloseTags = () => {
        const show: boolean = !opened;
        setOpen(show);
        const ids: Array<string> = getIdOfChildrens(branch);
        onUpdatedHiddenBranchs(ids, show);
    };

    const onUpdateFavorite = () => {
        onUpdateFavourites(branch);
    };

    const isCollapsed = () => {
        const index: number = hiddenBranchs.findIndex( (hiddenId: string) => hiddenId === branch.value);
        return (index >=0) ? true : false;
    };

    return (
        <>
            <div
                className={`go-hierarchy ${level} ${
                    isCollapsed() ? "collapsed" : ""
                }`}
                style={{ marginLeft: `${level * 15}px` }}
            >
                {branch.children && branch.children.length > 0 ? (
                    <div className="hirarchy-show" onClick={onOpenCloseTags}>
                        {opened ? (
                            <i className="icon-down-open" />
                        ) : (
                            <i className="icon-right-open" />
                        )}
                    </div>
                ) : <div className="hierarchy-hidden"></div>}
                <div
                    className={`go-hierarchy-branch ${
                        selectedId === id ? "active" : ""
                    } `}
                    onClick={onSelectDma}
                >
                    {!icon ? (
                        <div className="hierarchy-branch-favourite">
                            {opened ? (
                                <i className="icon-folder-open-empty" />
                            ) : (
                                <i className="icon-folder-empty" />
                            )}
                        </div>
                    ) : (
                        <>
                            {icon === "tag" ? (
                                <div className="hierarchy-branch-favourite">
                                    <i className="icon-tag" />
                                </div>
                            ) : (
                                <div
                                    className="hierarchy-branch-favourite"
                                    onClick={onUpdateFavorite}
                                >
                                    {!favourite ? (
                                        <i className="icon-bookmark-empty" />
                                    ) : (
                                        <i className="icon-bookmark" />
                                    )}
                                </div>
                            )}
                        </>
                    )}
                    <div className="hierarchy-branch-title">
                        <label>{label}</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            {children &&
                children.length > 0 &&
                children.map((child: IHierarchyBranch, index: number) => {
                    return renderHierarchyBranch(index, child);
                })}
        </>
    );
};

export default HierarchyBranch;
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please the below, it will help you understanding clear. In this way you can get collapsed view.

```
class App extends React.Component {
    state = { data: tree };

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div className='example-config'>
                    <button onClick={this.expandAll} className='k-button'>Expand all</button>
                    <button onClick={this.collapseAll} className='k-button'>Collapse all</button>
                </div>
                <TreeView data={this.state.data} expandIcons={true} onExpandChange={this.onExpandChange} />
            </div>
        );
    }
    expandAll = () => {
        this.setState({
            data: this.state.data.map(item => Object.assign({}, item, { expanded: true }))
        });
    }
    collapseAll = () => {
        this.setState({
            data: this.state.data.map(item => Object.assign({}, item, { expanded: false }))
        });
    }
    onExpandChange = (event) => {
        const data = this.state.data.slice();

        const itemIndex = data.indexOf(event.item);
        data[itemIndex] = { ...event.item };
        data[itemIndex].expanded = !data[itemIndex].expanded;

        this.setState({ data });
    }
}

const tree = [
    { text: 'Item1', items: [{ text: 'Item1.1' }, { text: 'Item1.2' }] },
    { text: 'Item2', items: [{ text: 'Item2.1' }, { text: 'Item2.2' }] },
    { text: 'Item3', items: [{ text: 'Item3.1' }, { text: 'Item3.2' }] },
    { text: 'Item4', items: [{ text: 'Item4.1' }, { text: 'Item4.2' }] },
    { text: 'Item5', items: [{ text: 'Item5.1' }, { text: 'Item5.2' }] },
    { text: 'Item6', items: [{ text: 'Item6.1' }, { text: 'Item6.2' }] }
];

ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.querySelector('my-app')
);
```

Comment: I need to work with id, not create a new property. Solution should be with redux